# Calculating angle between two vectors?

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, compass-geolocation

I'm developing an iOS app, which has to show POIs (points of interest) depending on device heading. I used `CLLocationManager` to get user's location and heading. I have one pair of destination's coordinates. Based on this I'm calculating which quarter is that and returning float value of deviation from south (0 degrees) in degrees. I have -/+180 degrees in the north and 0 in the south. Here is code snippet:

```
-(float)updateTargetLongitude:(float)lon Latitude:(float)lat{
//    //longitude = x
//    //latitude = y
      NSLog(@"current location = (%.5f, %.5f)", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"currentLongitude"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"currentLatitude"]);
      float x = lon - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"currentLongitude"];
      float y = lat - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"currentLatitude"];
      float angle;
      NSLog(@"Searching angle from source (%.5f, %.5f) to destination (%.5f, %.5f)", locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, lon, lat);
      if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
          NSLog(@"you're there already!");
          return -0.1;
      }
      if(x == 0 && y > 0){
          NSLog(@"look north");
          angle = 180.0;
      }
      if (x == 0 && y < 0) {
          NSLog(@"look south");
          angle = 0;
      }
      if (x > 0 && y == 0) {
          NSLog(@"look east");
          angle = 90.0;
      }
      if (x < 0 && y == 0) {
          NSLog(@"look west");
          angle = -90;
      }
      if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
          NSLog(@"first quarter");
          angle = -atan2f(y, x) - M_PI_2;
      }
      if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
          NSLog(@"second quarter");
          angle = atan2f(y, x) + M_PI_2;
      }
      if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
          NSLog(@"third quarter");
          angle = atan2f(x, y);
      }
      if (x > 0 && y < 0) {
          NSLog(@"fourth quarter");
          angle = -atan2f(x, y);
      }
      NSLog(@"returning radians angle = %.4f for (%.5f, %.5f) :: degrees = %.3f", angle, y, x, angle * 180 / M_PI);
      return angle * 180 / M_PI ;
}
```

Somehow I have situation, when target is in fourth quarter, but is -93 degrees from south. I'm lost and I don't have any idea how to fix that...

**edit:** by quarter I mean Cartesian coordinate system, where +y is north, +x is east and so on!

p.s.: I've read that iPhone compass is really bad, but if so how app like Google maps is working properly?

**edit2**: I made a mistake with angles. Oficially o have -90 degrees in east and 90 in west.

Comment: Side note:  Testing floating points for equality might not give you the results you expect.

Comment: yes, but looking exactly N/S/E/W is with device accuracy almost imposible, so this was strictly for "mathematical" purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I see it correctly, the formula

```
angle = atan2(x, -y) * 180.0/M_PI;
```

should work in all quadrants, making all the `if` statements unnecessary.

---

`atan2(y, x)` returns the angle between the vector `(x, y)` and the positive x-axis, the return value is always between `-pi` and `pi`.

Replacing `(y, x)` by `(x, -y)` in the arguments
means that the vector is rotated by 90 degrees, therefore the result of the above formula
is the angle measured to the negative y-axis, which is what you wanted.

---

*Update (according to "edit2" in the question):* If the requirement is "south = 0 deg", "east = -90 deg",  "west = +90 deg" then the formula would be

```
angle = atan2(-x, -y) * 180.0/M_PI;
```

Comment: facing south I have 0 degrees, to east is -, to west is +, so I guess it should be finally atan2(-x,-y), right?

Comment: @FilipChwastowski: For x > 0, y == 0 my formula gives angle = 90 degrees, I thought that is what you wanted.

Comment: nah, I did mention that I have -/+180 degrees in north ;) please edit your answer so nobody will get lost where finally +/- degree direction is so I can accept ;)

Comment: @FilipChwastowski: Sorry, I am confused now. In your question you have the code `if (x > 0 && y == 0) { NSLog(@"look east"); angle = 90.0; }`, so I based my answer on that. So you actually want angle = -90 for the east direction?

Comment: my bad, sorry - of course you are right, once again apology :) answer accepted ;)

Comment: I edited my question, so nobody will get confuse ;) could you can now edit answer so it will fit :) thx again!

Answer (score 1):

The `atan2` function already takes quadrant into account.  In other words, it "knows" that you're in the third quadrant if both `x` and `y` are negative.  Knowing that, you can see what the angle output for `atan2(y, x)` is, and then change it to how you want it displayed.

The main reason why Google maps works even with a relatively inaccurate compass is that the structures of the roads give you hints, so you can get by with a bigger error than if you didn't know where the roads were.

Comment: are you sure it "knows"? what if x * y > 0 ? it's possible with situations: both < 0 or both > 0 ...

Comment: Yes. That's why you supply atan2 with two arguments.  If `x` and `y` are both negative, you're in quadrant III.  If they're both positive, you're in quadrant I, etc.  The output of atan2 will be between pi and -pi (I think).  That's the whole circle.

Comment: arctg(alfa) is always between -pi/2 and pi/2 ;)

Comment: That's exactly the difference between arctg(alpha) and atan2(y, x). The arctangent of 1 *can be* either 45 degrees (or 225 degrees, or 405 degrees, ...) but arctg(1) is pi/4 (it chooses the one between -pi and pi).  But then atan2(1, 1) != atan2(-1, -1). atan2(1, 1) is pi/4, but atan2(-1, -1) is -3pi/4.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after deciding what quadrant it is I changed code to always calculate atan2 with positive values of x and y - now it works!