# Finding an angle with 3 CGPoints

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, math, drawrect

In my application, a user taps 3 times and an angle will be created by the 3 points that were tapped. It draws the angle perfectly. I am trying to calculate the angle at the second tap, but I think I am doing it wrong (probably a math error). I haven't covered this in my calculus class yet, so I am going off of a formula on wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Here is what I am trying:

Note: First, Second, and Third are `CGPoints` created at the user's tap.

```
        CGFloat xDistA = (second.x - third.x);
        CGFloat yDistA = (second.y - third.y);
        CGFloat a = sqrt((xDistA * xDistA) + (yDistA * yDistA));

        CGFloat xDistB = (first.x - third.x);
        CGFloat yDistB = (first.y - third.y);
        CGFloat b = sqrt((xDistB * xDistB) + (yDistB * yDistB));

        CGFloat xDistC = (second.x - first.x);
        CGFloat yDistC = (second.y - first.y);
        CGFloat c = sqrt((xDistC * xDistC) + (yDistC * yDistC));

        CGFloat angle = acos(((a*a)+(b*b)-(c*c))/((2*(a)*(b))));

        NSLog(@"FULL ANGLE IS: %f, ANGLE IS: %.2f",angle, angle);
```

Sometimes, it gives the angle as 1 which doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone explain why this is, or how to fix it please?

Comment: Your formula gives the angle at the *third* point.

Comment: @MartinR: What would I alter to make it the second point?

Comment: `CGFloat angle = acos(((a*a)+(c*c)-(b*b))/((2*(a)*(c))));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Not sure if this is the main problem but it is a problem*

Your answer gives the angle at the wrong point:

[image]

To get the angle in green (which is probably angle you want based on your variable names "first", "second" and "third), use:

`CGFloat angle = acos(((a*a)+(c*c)-(b*b))/((2*(a)*(c))));`

Comment: Thank you! Very useful graphic! I don't know what the world would do without people who know how to do math.

Comment: I added this to avoid zero division: `CGFloat angle = 0.0;
    CGFloat numerator = ((a*a)+(c*c)-(b*b)) ;
    if (numerator != 0 ) {
        angle = acos( numerator / ((2*(a)*(c))) );
    }`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way that circumvents the law of cosines and instead calculates the angles of the two vectors. The difference between the angles is the searched value:

```
CGVector vec1 = { first.x - second.x, first.y - second.y };
CGVector vec2 = { third.x - second.x, third.y - second.y };

CGFloat theta1 = atan2f(vec1.dy, vec1.dx);
CGFloat theta2 = atan2f(vec2.dy, vec2.dx);

CGFloat angle = theta1 - theta2;
NSLog(@"angle: %.1f°, ", angle / M_PI * 180);
```

Note the `atan2` function that takes the x and y components as separate arguments and thus avoids the 0/90/180/270° ambiguity.

Comment: It is probably a matter of taste, but I always use CGPoint (which has x and y "components").

Comment: @MartinR It's a longstanding Cocoa convention to use CGSize for distances. It will probably take me a while to find a reference, though. I'm sure I've seen it in Apple code.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, this answer is very helpful! This works, but it returns a negative number every time and gets larger than 180 (After 180 it needs to become smaller) so I will stick with the answer I chose but with a little tweaking this works too!

Comment: It's more correct to use `CGVector` I believe. And congrats! I was very slow in writing my answer, so you've beat me :)

Comment: @Josue, you could normalize it with `if (angle < 0) angle += 360`.

Comment: @ilyan. There's no `CGVector` in Foundation or any Apple framework I'm aware of.

Comment: I wasn't aware of CGVector until now, but it *is* defined in CGGeometry.h.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe; indeed, it's only from iOS 7: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Oh my, you know you're getting old when you notice that you stopped reading the API diffs three major versions before :) Thanks, ilya! `CGVector` really seems suitable.

Answer (score 1):

The cosine formula implementation looks right; did you take into account that `acos()` returns the angle in radians, not in degrees? In order to convert into degrees, multiply the angle by 180 and divide by Pi (3.14159...).

Comment: When I draw a 90 deg angle, it returns 45? `((angle*180)/3.14);`

Comment: Looks like wrong point. You're now calculating the angle at the third point (since c is second-first); which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done it is to calculate the two angles separately using `atan2(y,x)` then using this function.

```
static inline double
AngleDiff(const double Angle1, const double Angle2)
{
    double diff = 0;
    diff = fabs(Angle1 - Angle2);
    if (diff > <Pi>) {
        diff = (<2Pi>) - diff;
    }
    return diff;
}
```

The function deals in radians, but you can change `<Pi>` to 180 and `<2Pi>` to 360

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716244/calculating-angle-between-two-vectors) to compute angle of the vector:

```
CGFloat angleForVector(CGFloat dx, CGFloat dy) {
    return atan2(dx, -dy) * 180.0/M_PI;
}

// Compute angle at point Corner, that is between AC and BC:

CGFloat angle = angleForVector(A.x - Corner.x, A.y - Corner.y)
              - angleForVector(B.x - Corner.x, B.y - Corner.y);

NSLog(@"FULL ANGLE IS: %f, ANGLE IS: %.2f",angle, angle);
```

Comment: This is more or less what Nikolai suggested in his answer.

Comment: Well, yes, it just  took me more than 10 minutes to write :)

Comment: @ilyan. Note that you mixed up the x and y components in the `atan2` call (it's y, x order). As we're only interested in the difference of two angles it does not matter in this case, though.